# An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed. when I compiled using ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript

I compiled my project and I am getting error as "An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed."
Firstly I clone my project from GitLab. Then follow the steps
1)npm install
2)ng serve --open

Dependencies looks like :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?
Help me to find out the way.

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: version is v12.16.1

Comment: did you try `rm -rf node_module package-lock.json yarn.lock` and `npm install` again?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried above and its giving message as "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'"